# Heroku Connect - Validation error when trying to create map for Salesforce Chatter objects

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, salesforce-chatter

I'm testing the Heroko Connect addon and receiving an error when trying to sync objects related to Chatter, namely:

- FeedComment
- FeedLike

I was able to sync FeedItem and User, but receiving the following message on the above objects:

```
Unable to create mapping for 'FeedLike'. {"error": "{u'CreatedDate': {}, u'FeedItemId': {}, u'Id': {}, u'CreatedById': {}, u'IsDeleted': {}, u'InsertedById': {}} is not valid under any of the given schemas"}. Status code: 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am using a Developer Org as the Sys Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting Heroku Support, I received this response. Sounds like a no go for now.

> The issue with FeedComment and FeedLike is that you cannot query them
>   directly without querying the parents first. Eg for feedLikes you can
>   only query the table when you specify a parent of the like. At this
>   time we're not able to sync these objects as a result.